# What is the use of localtime `time` in perl?

Tags: perl

I tried the first perl program, like this :

```
print "My First Perl Program!\n";
$name ="Anto Aravinth";
print "Hello $name your age now is ";
$byear = 1991;
my($se,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday) = localtime time;
$age=($year+1900)-$byear;
print $age;
```

Which produces the output :

```
My First Perl Program!
Hello Anto Aravinth your age now is 20
```

I understood the logic, but have some doubts. In this line `my($se,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday) = localtime time;` i know its returning the current timezone value to 9 distinct variables. Now I want to know what that `time` is for in this line, because without the `time` also I'm getting the output. So whether it is needed to insert `time` or not?

And I want to get the `year`  directly without typing all those `9` names, is there a way to do so?

Comment: (removed your first question, which was not a good question for SO)

Comment: @Mat : Oh sorry and thanks as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`time` returns the current time, counted in seconds since the system's epoch. (Usually: 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC, but see the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html) for an exception).

`localtime` takes a time expressed in that format, and returns the human-understandable parts of the date that corresponds to (in the current timezone).

If you don't give an argument to `localtime`,

> "localtime()" uses the current time (as returned by time(3)).

So you could omit `time` from that expression in your case.

If you only care about the year, you can do this:

```
my $se = (localtime)[5];
```

Although I prefer to be more explicit anyway:

```
my $se = (localtime(time()))[5];
```

Comment: 1970, 1977. What's 221 million seconds between friends?

Comment: @daxim: `time` in perl doesn't necessarily return seconds since the "standard" unix epoch. See perlfunc linked above.

Answer (score 7):

The first place to look for answers to questions like this is the Perl documentation. The [documentation for localtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) contains the answer to your first question.

> If EXPR is omitted, localtime() uses the current time (as returned by
>   time(3)).

Others have given one way to get just the year from localtime (using a list slice), but the documentation mentions the [Time::localtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/localtime.html) module which offers a different approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::localtime;

say 'The year is ', localtime->year + 1900;
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl manpage states "If EXPR is omitted, "localtime()" uses the current time (as returned by time(3)).", so you don't need to call time function explicitly.

On your second question, you can simply do

```
print 1900 + (localtime)[5]
```

to access year information directly.

Comment: I guess `7` should not come here and `5` is the correct way as Mat answered. Isn't?